# Is it possible to get info via JSON RPC about --no-ancient-blocks flag for an openethereum node?

Tags: parity, openethereum

It's possible to run an openethereum node with --no-ancient-blocks flag.

How can I check that a node was started with this flag via JSON RPC call?